# 'FirebaseStorage' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultInstance'

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-storage

when I try to add the below code to the controller in the .NET core project, I get the error that, 'FirebaseStorage' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultInstance'

```
using Firebase.Storage;
using FirebaseAdmin;

FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.GetInstance("my-firebase-project-name");
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance.GetBucket("my-default-bucket-url");
```

And I also get the almost same error in the following line of code also,
It shows the 'FirebaseStorage' does not contain a definition for 'GetReference' and no accessible extension method 'GetReference' accepting a first argument of type 'FirebaseStorage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
var reference = storage.GetReference($"images/{imageFilename}");
```

Am I missing something? or is that the NuGet package just doesn't support the DefaultInstance and GetReference ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Firebase Admin SDK Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin). The Admin SDK for .NET only provides APIs for authentication. This [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet) shows classes within the .NET SDK.

- FirebaseAdmin
- FirebaseAdmin.Auth
- FirebaseAdmin.Messaging

As of the moment, Cloud Storage is not yet supported in C# with the AdminSDK. Check out the matrix in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#c).

You can file for a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) through Firebase.

Comment: I have shared the feature request through the firebase console, thank you for the info and hopefully i will be getting an update in 2 days.